# Speeding up the code for downloading data from Telegram and saving it to a CSV file

Tags: python, string, csv, file, telethon

I implemented the following function, which I would like to speed up as much as possible:

```
async def async_update_database(self, source_id: str, source_hash: str, message_id_1: str, message_id_n: str, file: str):

        entity = types.InputPeerChannel(int(source_id), int(source_hash))

        n_messages = 0
        n_comments = 0

        with open(file, 'a', encoding = "utf-8") as fout:
            for message_id in range(int(message_id_1), int(message_id_n) + 1):
                message = await self.client.get_messages(entity, ids = message_id)
                if message == None or message.message == "" or message.replies == None or message.replies.replies == 0:
                    continue

                fout.write("M," + str(int(message.date.timestamp())) + ',' + str(message_id) + ',' + repr(message.message) + '\n')
                n_messages += 1

                async for comment in self.client.iter_messages(entity, reply_to = message_id):
                    if isinstance(comment.sender, types.User) and not comment.sender.bot:
                        fout.write("C," + str(int(comment.date.timestamp())) + ',' + str(comment.sender.id) + ',' + repr(comment.message) + '\n')
                        n_comments += 1

        return (str(n_messages) + " " + str(n_comments))
```

The function is called from external code, requests data for posts and comments on them from Telegram channels, downloads them and saves them in CSV format to a file. There are a lot of calls, so writing to the file is set to append to end mode. Download volumes: one call to this function can download 10'000 posts, 1000 comments in each, i.e. 10'000'000 lines are written to the file.

What can you do with this code? I'm not a Python expert, I might have some stupid mistakes here. From what seems to me not very optimal: 1) Does writing to the end of the file work effectively in this form? 2) Are there any problems with asynchronous calls? 3) Am I using functions from the Telethon library correctly?

Comment: Basic mistake (not performance-related): Not using the `csv` module to write the file. CSV is nigh *impossible* to get right, and you should always use it for correctness in whichever dialect you intend to use (you'd also need to open the file with `newline=''` to make it avoid line-ending translations so the CSV follows the chosen dialect's line ending format, not the OS default).

Comment: As far as performance goes, this is almost certainly going to be network I/O bound, nothing is going to make a meaningful difference on performance aside from getting a bigger pipe. The append mode is perfectly functional, and if the code otherwise works, I don't know what you expect as far as answers go.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm considering using several accounts to use their api id/hash to load data in parallel mode, but possibly it will require different servers and IP addresses

Comment: Knowing absolutely nothing about Telegram's terms of service, I can almost guarantee that's violating them. It may or may not be illegal in your jurisdiction, but if you want to not have your accounts shut off for violations, I'd strongly suggest *not* doing that.

Comment: Concurrency is an issue. what happens when the second call starts before the first call finished? => You cannot use the same `file`. I would replace csv with storing stuff in a nosql database, or a graph database.

Comment: @Ouss not a problem, 2 different calls for different channels, they will save data to different files, so there will be no problem with syncronization

Comment: @ShadowRanger I do not see any problems with reading public data from channels by using API connections from different accounts of different people. What if you will use my code to download the same data?

Comment: What about if a new call to the same channel was made, before the first one finished? Is that a possible scenario?

Comment: @Ouss no, currently I am awaiting all async calls before starting a new iteration of loading

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently does not actually use any of the advantages of `async` (when only thinking about this endpoint). By calling `await` within the for loop, or `async for` later, you are effectively treating these `async` calls synchronously, and each will only execute after the other finishes. While this would still help to allow for `async` calls in other FastAPI endpoints, you are not doing any `async` optimization here.

You may be able to improve performance by using [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), and passing a list of functions to execute asynchronously "in parallel" (this is not *really* in parallel but it's a good enough analogy). The first section of your code around the `await` would turn in to something like:

```py
import functools


message_ids = list(range(int(message_id_1), int(message_id_n) + 1))
# create a partial function with "entity" already passed
get_messages_func = functools.partial(self.client.get_messages, entity)
messages = await asyncio.gather(get_messages_func, message_ids)
```

And messages should end up as a list of messages. The difference here being that the `client.get_messages` calls will not wait for the previous call to *return* before starting, but will start as soon as the previous call *starts*, and will return as soon as it receives a response. Applying this methodology to the second async call may improve performance as well.

The major gotcha I could think of here is your program running out of memory, since it would not process all requests and their return values "at the same time", meaning there wouldn't be any time to garbage collect old responses before parsing the new ones. You may be able to work around this by setting a limit on how many requests you process (`gather`) at a time.

Comment: The bigger problem is that a single network call is being per message. `get_messages` is capable of fetching more than one message at a time. Or better yet, don't fetch by IDs, but by offset.